# Internet speed monitor for windows 7

Tags: windows-7, internet, internet-speed, widgets

I have a tool on my android device that displays the amount of bytes uploaded and downloaded at any given time by all applications on the phone (ex. 5Kb/s, 10Mb/s). Is there any tool on windows 7 that can do the same thing? Perhaps a desktop widget. I've searched this site and google but I can't find one.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just looking for a small network monitoring tool, you can use the gadget [Network Meter](http://addgadgets.com/network_meter/).

If you're really into something more complete (monitoring for any application), [NetLimiter](https://www.netlimiter.com/download) is a match.

Version 4 is still officially in testing phase. It is free if your register as a user (which is also free). I use it daily and it is more stable now that it was before (lots of software crashes used to happen).

Version 3 is stable and available as a freeware but only for systems before Windows 8.

As you see, you can use either of them, your choice.

Answer (score 2):

Start Resource Monitor (`resmon.exe`), and click the `Network` tab. It shows which applications are using the internet and uploading/downloading at what speed.

[image]

[Which Program is Using all of Your Internet Bandwidth? Use Resource Monitor to Find it.](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/program-using-internet-resource-monitor/)